# separate row by groups and flatten column information

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

The problem setting

I have a table

```
id    type    x    y
1     type1   1.0  2.0
2     type2   1.2  2.3
3     type1   1.2  2.4
```

I want to separate x,y of type1 and type2 like following:

```
id    x_type1   y_type1  x_type2    y_type2
1     1.0       2.0       
2                        1.2        2.3
3     1.2       2.4
```

How can I implement this in postgresql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when type = 'type1' then x end) as x_type1,
       max(case when type = 'type1' then y end) as y_type1,
       max(case when type = 'type2' then x end) as x_type2,
       max(case when type = 'type3' then y end) as y_type2
from table t
group by t.id;
```